# Error running kustomization : no matches for kind "Kustomization" in version "http://kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

I am trying to run kubectl apply for kustomization.yaml and getting below error

E0316 17:33:20.781816   12333 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for http://external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: Got empty response for: http://external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
E0316 17:33:21.138951   12333 memcache.go:255] couldn't get resource list for http://external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: Got empty response for: http://external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
error: resource mapping not found for name: "" namespace: "" from "./kustomization.yaml": no matches for kind "Kustomization" in version "http://kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first

I can successfully execute

Kubectl kustomize .

However, having issue running kubectl apply -f kustomization.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kubectl apply -f kustomization.yaml` is wrong, because kustomization.yaml isn't a kubernetes manifest to apply. You want `kubectl apply -k .`